# "TypeError: Bool is not iterable" in any() iteration with boolean criteria

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python 2.7, I want to check the similarity between one string, and strings in a list, until it finds a match.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

correctList = ["thanks", "believe", "definitely"]

myString = "thansk"

for correctWord in correctList:
    ratio = similar(correctWord, myString)
    if ratio > 0.9:
        myString = correctWord
        break

print myString
>>> "thanks"
```

I would like to simplify the `for` iteration into fewer lines, to something like:

```
if similar(myString, any([correctWord for correctWord in correctList])) > 0.9:
    myString = correctWord
```

I'm not entirely sure about the correct logic here, but in either case variants of this syntax throws the error:

> TypeError: ("'bool' object is not iterable", u'occurred at index 0')

What would be the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: `any` checks the boolean-ness of every element of a sequence and returns True if any of then were considered True and False if they were all false, what are you trying to use it for instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are stopping as soon as you find the first string with similarity > 0.9, starting with `"thansk"` as a candidate. So I think this is equivalent:

```
myString = "thansk"

myString = next((w for w in correctList if similar(w, myString) > 0.9), myString)
```

Comment: if none of the cases work it does not default to `"thansk"` it raises a StopIteration.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen if you specify a default value like `None` when calling `next` it will avoid that problem

Comment: to specify a fallback you need to pass it as the second argument to `next`, in this case it would be `"thansk"`

Comment: @oldrinb thank you for catching that and editing. I was just about to fix it, but you beat me to it!

Comment: @Winterflags if you are using `exec` elsewhere in your code that would result in that error, but there is no way that adding the code posted in this answer would be the result of that error.

Answer (score 2):

`any` should only take a list of boolean expressions, so we need to find a way to evaluating `similar` between `myString` and every element of `correctList` first. We can use `map` here alongside a predicate `lambda s: similar(myString, s) > 0.9`:

```
any(map(lambda s: similar(s, myString) > 0.9, correctList))
```

This evaluates to `True` if there is at least one element of `correctList` 'similar enough' to `myString`.

---

... but you'll notice that we want to determine *which* elements of `correctList` are similar to `myString`, so perhaps we should really be using `filter`:

```
candidates = filter(lambda s: similar(s, myString) > 0.9, correctList)
```

You **could** just take the first result, in which case the `next` expression would work, but it wouldn't necessarily be the *most similar* element of `correctList`.

---

We can, however, use `map`, `filter`, and `max` to accomplish that. Consider:

```
pairs = map(lambda s: (s, similar(s, myString)), correctList)
```

returns a list of pairs, each consisting of an element of `correctList` and its 'degree of similarity' with `myString`. We can then filter out the candidates with similarity below `0.9`:

```
pairs = filter(lambda (s, d): d > 0.9, pairs)
```

and lastly we choose the candidate with maximum similarity from those remaining (using `operator.itemgetter` as our key function) or `myString` if none exists:

```
myString = (max(pairs, key = itemgetter(1)) or [myString])[0]
```

Of course, we could also use `max` without pre-filtering and then disregard the answer if its similarity is insufficient:

```
pairs = map(lambda s: (s, similar(s, myString)), correctList)
candidate = max(pairs, key = itemgetter(1))
myString = candidate[0] if candidate[1] > 0.9 else myString
```

Comment: filter will return a list or iterator of all cases that worked, not the first.  if using python 3 you can simply call `next()` on the result of filter with the default specified appropriately but there is no simple work around for python 2.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen of course, that's why I said *which* and used the plural form of *candidate*; we can use the built-in `next` in Python 2.6+, however, to determine the *first* such candidate:
`next((s for s in correctList if similar(s, myString) > 0.9), myString)`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen the reason I don't suggest doing so is simply that the most similar candidate might not be the first in our list as we're not ordering the results by similarity

Comment: @oldrinb I have checked both answers and they both work. I have to accept one answer, but yours might be better utilized in the sense that further filtering can be implemented if there are multiple matches above ratio *0.9*. Right now I would just get `candidates[0]`.

Comment: understood, @Winterflags -- I also demonstrated one way of determining the most similar candidate with sufficient similarity

Comment: @Winterflags you should re-accept lurker's answer as it most closely matches the code you gave in the OP -- I don't mind. I'm just glad to exercise my rusty Python skills :)

Comment: @oldrinb That was my thinking initially, but a "completionist" answer is also good.